# NodeJS table children are undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, roblox

I've been working on a discord/roblox bot. I've gotten almost finished, but ran into a problem. I'm a noob at node, so please dont harp too much if the code is bad. What this does is I click a button in a roblox game, it sends a POST request to a heroku app, and then with the info provided it sends a message to a channel in my discord server.

Relevant bits of code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
    app = express();
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const bot = new Discord.Client();

function GetData(id){
    let url = "https://economy.roblox.com/v1/assets/"+id+"/resale-data";
    let url2 = "https://thumbnails.roblox.com/v1/assets?assetIds="+id+"&size=150x150&format=Png";
    let url3 = "http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId="+id

    let options = {json: true};

    var response = {};

    request(url, options, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error)
        };

        if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            response.rap = body.recentAveragePrice
            console.log(response)
        };
    });

    request(url2, options, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error)
        };

        if(!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            response.thumbnail = body.data[0].imageUrl
            console.log(response)
        }
    });

    request(url3, options, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error)
        };

        if(!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            response.name = body.Name
            console.log(response)
        }
    });

    return response
};

app.post('/exec', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        success: true
    }));
    console.log("working");
    console.log(req.body)
    var data = GetData(req.body.id)
    if (req.body.state === true){
        var state = "New Projected"
    } else {
        var state = "No longer projected"
    }
    const msg = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription(data.name)
        .setAuthor(state)
        .setColor(0x1c90d9)
        .addField("RAP:", data.rap)
        .setImage(data.thumbnail)
    bot.channels.get("655196831835226133").send(msg);
});
```

However, this is the message that is sent in the discord server:

everything is undefined and there is no thumbnail

[image]

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the output near the bottom where you do `console.log(req.body);`? And also what is the output if you log the `var data` object to the console before you create the `msg` ?

Comment: @chrisbyte `{ id: '6789', state: true }`, which is what I sent from Roblox. It's not part of my problem. Also, the output of the `data` log is an empty table? Hmm....

Comment: @chrisbyte But the logs from the function itself inside the `request`s return a valid table: `{name: "Figure1", thumbnail: "long link thing"}`

Comment: Based on that, I would suspect that the `request` calls inside `GetData`are asynchronous and the data is not available yet by the time you do `return response`. Are you familiar with `Promise` or async/await in javascript? https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait  You need to wait for the actual data to return from the request **before** you can move on to the next request and then finally return.

Comment: @chrisbyte No, I  am not. Can you educate me a little on that please?

Answer (score 0):

Some reading here: https://www.promisejs.org/

Asynchronous functions, like making a request to a server, take time to return and do so in a callback. You have to keep track of the paths of the callbacks to make sure you do not do the next step before a previous step has completed otherwise you will skip over it entirely. It is not like calling a regular function that does something in order.

When you do `return response` at the end of `GetData`, there is nothing in the object because you need to wait for the three responses to complete within their respective callbacks. You are seeing things logged to the console because they are happening after the fact in the background. If you were to put timestamps and additional logging, you would see that it is not all happening in the order of how you wrote it, but rather in order of when the requests themselves complete.

There are many different ways to write and use promises, but a very simple one here would be to nest the requests so they happen one after the other, and then finally `resolve` the promise at the very end when your `response` object has all the data. With Promises you `resolve` which is the same as returning, and `reject` when you want to raise an error.

Without going too deep into it, here is an example of what you can do. This is untested as I am not running your application or trying to rewrite it, that is not was StackOverflow is for, but hopefully it can send you in the right direction. Note that I call `reject` on the errors to tell the promise to stop running.

```
function GetData(id){

  // declare the Promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let url = "https://economy.roblox.com/v1/assets/"+id+"/resale-data";
    let url2 = "https://thumbnails.roblox.com/v1/assets?assetIds="+id+"&size=150x150&format=Png";
    let url3 = "http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId="+id

    let options = {json: true};

    var response = {};

    // make request 1
    request(url, options, (error1, res1, body1) => {
        if (error1) {
            console.log(error1)

            // reject
            reject(error1);
        };

        if (!error1 && res1.statusCode == 200) {

            // all good, continue

            response.rap = body1.recentAveragePrice
            console.log(response)

            // make request 2
            request(url2, options, (error2, res2, body2) => {
              if (error2) {
                console.log(error2)

                // reject
                reject(error2);
              };

              if(!error2 && res2.statusCode == 200) {

                  // all good, continue

                  response.thumbnail = body2.data[0].imageUrl
                  console.log(response)

                  // make request 3
                  request(url3, options, (error3, res3, body3) => {
                    if (error3) {
                      console.log(error3)

                      // reject
                      reject(error3);
                    };

                    if(!error3 && res3.statusCode == 200) {
                        response.name = body3.Name
                        console.log(response)

                        // finally, resolve the final response object
                        resolve(response);
                    }
                });
              }
          });
        };
    });
  });
};
```

Now to the calling function. You still call `GetData()` but you use the `then()` function to get what was resolved, or `catch()` to catch any errors. I would also suggest putting your `res.send()` functions at the end, unless you absolutely need to return right away as your originally wrote it.

```
app.post('/exec', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    console.log("working");
    console.log(req.body)

    // get all the data as a Promise
    GetData(req.body.id)
      .then((data) => {

        // now you have your data!

        if (req.body.state === true){
            var state = "New Projected"
        } else {
            var state = "No longer projected"
        }
        const msg = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setDescription(data.name)
            .setAuthor(state)
            .setColor(0x1c90d9)
            .addField("RAP:", data.rap)
            .setImage(data.thumbnail)
        bot.channels.get("655196831835226133").send(msg);

        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            success: true
        }));
      })
      .catch((err) => {

        // you can handle errors here that were rejected in the promise, if necessary

        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            success: false
        }));

      })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get virtually the same error... `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined`. Also, I'm sure it exists as I have seen it in the output before.